# Rails and Neo4j: Found neo4j (1.3.1) but was for platform java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, neo4j

I am trying to install the neo4j gem, I have installed JRuby 1.6.7, but I get the above error every time. I've tried googling the problem and cannot find the answer, I'd appreciate some help. How do I install the neo4j gem?

`gem install neo4j` gives the above error.

Comment: did you use rvm to install it ?

Comment: Yes (I presume you mean JRuby?).

Comment: I have answered my own question. As I used RVM to install JRuby, clearly JRuby is a Ruby Version, so I needed to select that as the in use version of Ruby. It now works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why I asked if you used rvm to install it .
If you're running on linux/mac you can install zsh with oh-my-zsh and get a [prompt theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes) that will show you the current rvm ruby version . 
 That will help with situations like this . 
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh